Probability when unfair coins are being used.
A and B are independently tossing their coin. Their coins have a probability of 0.25 of getting a head. After each of them toss their coin twice, we see a total of 2 heads. What is the probability that Mr. A got exactly 1 head?
I have tried finding it using conditional probability and the answer I am getting is 2/3, but I am not too sure about my answer. If someone could please confirm it?

Is there a reason behind why I am getting downvoted?

Consider showing your work, not just your answer.

That being said, it seems to me that the fact the coin is weighted is a red herring here since both coins are weighted the same.  We are told exactly two heads occurred.  Each of HHTT, HTHT, HTTH, THHT, THTH, TTHH are equally likely to have occurred, and in four of those six we have Mr. A having gotten one head.  Your answer seems correct.  The question would have been far more interesting had Mr. A had a coin who lands head with probability $p$ and Mr. B a coin who lands head with probability $q$ where $q$ could be different than $p$.
